# Redirecting 404 error with subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

How i redirect **404 pag**e error subdomain link.

Example:

```
domain.com/46444
```

link show 404 not found.

How i redirect for

```
subdomain.domain.com/4644
```

This page i have normal page

```
subdomain.domain.com/4644
```

.htaccess link add one is not an option.

I have 200 000 link.